# appengine-web.xml not added to snapshot

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I tried to Deploy my Code to Google Cloud Using IntelliJ IDEA but i always get the Error that Appengine-web.xml is not Located in Snapshot

```html
Reading application configuration data...
Okt 07, 2018 11:19:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SCHWERWIEGEND: Received exception processing C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Dokumente/Projekte/Triebwerk 42/AusbauMeister/target/AusbauMeister-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate C:\Users\Alexa\OneDrive\Dokumente\Projekte\Triebwerk 42\AusbauMeister\target\AusbauMeister-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:141)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:75)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:265)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:542)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readWar(AppCfg.java:328)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readApplication(AppCfg.java:281)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:209)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:118)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:114)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Alexa\OneDrive\Dokumente\Projekte\Triebwerk 42\AusbauMeister\target\AusbauMeister-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:137)
 ... 8 more

Bad configuration: Could not locate C:\Users\Alexa\OneDrive\Dokumente\Projekte\Triebwerk 42\AusbauMeister\target\AusbauMeister-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
  Caused by: C:\Users\Alexa\OneDrive\Dokumente\Projekte\Triebwerk 42\AusbauMeister\target\AusbauMeister-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
Please see the logs [C:\Users\Alexa\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg1838607911937492436.log] for further information.
Failed to deploy '[2018-10-07 23:19:19] Maven build: AusbauMeister. Project: . Version: auto': Deployment failed due to staging failing with exit code: 1.
```

In my Project Structure it is Located under Web- Web-INF-appengine-web.xml

This is my appengine-web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>KARL</application><!-- unused for Cloud SDK based tooling -->
<version>Karl-001</version><!-- unused for Cloud SDK based tooling -->
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

and this is my Pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>AusbauMeister</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> <!-- REQUIRED -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> <!-- REQUIRED -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> <!-- REQUIRED -->
        <appengine.maven.plugin>1.3.2</appengine.maven.plugin>
        <jetty.maven.plugin>9.4.3.v20170317</jetty.maven.plugin>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>                          <!-- Used for local debugging -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.65</version>
            </plugin>

            
        </plugins>
    </build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>
</project>
```

I Also tried to Run it out of GCloud Console and with an artifact instead of maven with the Same Problems.

When i run it on the Local GAE everything looks fine.

Thanks for Reading!

Comment: How exactly are you trying to deploy the app from IntelliJ? Via the Google Cloud Tools plugin deployment run configuration?
https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-std

I noticed you also have two different maven app engine plugins.  Assuming you're using gcloud I'd just use the com.google.cloud.tools appengine-maven-plugin v 1.3.2.  You should probably try running `mvn appengine:deploy` and let us know if that also errors out in the same way.

Comment: To follow up on what @PatrickFlynn said, if you are attempting to deploy using the plugin run configuration, could you please provide the version of the plugin you are using? settings -> plugins -> google cloud tools

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you're help! 
I just figured out what the problem was. I said to intellij that my appengine-web.xml is in my web directory, but it was pointing to an different directory which does not exist and kept pointing to it no matter 
what I did.
 I created it and copied the files into this directory and now it is working fine.